# Is this a correct way to confirm Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) method's suitability for analysis? An example

Tags: r, regression, survival, mortality

I need to conduct an adjusted survival analysis, however, Cox PH assumption was not met and data stratification isn't a good solution as one of my study groups already has a small number of patients. Thus, I tried to fit my first AFT model, however, I am not sure if everything is fine. Is the following approach OK for answering my study question?

**Study question:** to compared adjusted survival of two patient groups, A (n=11000) and B (n=50)

**Follow up time:** 460 days

**Variables used for adjusting:** age (50-100), sex (m/f), comorbidity(integer, 0-12)

**The approach I used (my current best understanding of AFT)**

**1. I run AFT models with different distributions (here I only show two models to reduce the length of this post)**

```
library(flexsurv)
fit_genf = flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group, dist="genf", data = data)
fit_llogis = flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group, dist="llogis", data = data)
```

**2. Then I plot the models to assess their fit with the data and choose the best**

```
plot(fit_genf)
```

[Plot: Generalised F distribution AFT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK0XV.png)

```
plot(fit_llogis)
```

[Plot: Logistic scale distribution AFT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSHyh.png)

**3. Then I check their log-likelihoods and choose the best**

```
fit_genf$loglik
```

-29540.38

```
fit_llogis$loglik
```

-29748.55

**4. Then I check their AIC values and choose the best**

```
fit_genf$AIC
```

59090.77

```
fit_llogis$AIC
```

59503.1

**5. RESULT: Generalised F distribution AFT modelling (fit_genf) is an acceptable method for my analysis since this had the best fit, better log-likelihood and smaller AIC. Or is something wrong in my approach (large AIC number, log-likelihood etc)?**

Full fit_genf model summary:

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = data, 
    dist = "genf")

Estimates: 
        data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)
mu            NA    4.82150   4.29511   5.34788   0.26857        NA
sigma         NA    2.37833   1.89590   2.98351   0.27509        NA
Q             NA   -2.79284  -3.71926  -1.86641   0.47267        NA
P             NA    2.22999   1.05947   4.69368   0.84675        NA
groupB   0.00433    0.62147  -0.29332   1.53627   0.46674   1.86167
        L95%      U95%    
mu            NA        NA
sigma         NA        NA
Q             NA        NA
P             NA        NA
groupB   0.74578   4.64721

N = 11541,  Events: 3851,  Censored: 7690
Total time at risk: 4024558
Log-likelihood = -29540.38, df = 5
AIC = 59090.77
```

*ADDED AFTER CARLO'S RESPONSE*

**6. COMPLETE MODEL, named "final"**

```
final = flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ group + sex + 
        age + comorbidity, data = data, dist = "gompertz")
final


Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ group + sex + 
    age + comorbidity, data = data, dist = "gompertz")

Estimates: 
                   data mean   est         L95%        U95%        se          exp(est)    L95%        U95%      
shape                      NA  -0.1679218  -0.1766458  -0.1591978   0.0044511          NA          NA          NA
rate                       NA   0.0005775   0.0004209   0.0007923   0.0000932          NA          NA          NA
groupB              0.0043324  -0.2059110  -0.7134321   0.3016101   0.2589441   0.8139055   0.4899597   1.3520339
sexFemale           0.7172689  -0.4684015  -0.5421893  -0.3946137   0.0376475   0.6260021   0.5814739   0.6739403
age                78.7702972   0.0615099   0.0576167   0.0654030   0.0019863   1.0634410   1.0593089   1.0675892
comorbidity         1.6603414   0.1387881   0.1209541   0.1566220   0.0090991   1.1488806   1.1285732   1.1695534

N = 11541,  Events: 3851,  Censored: 7690
Total time at risk: 132299.7
Log-likelihood = -15802.47, df = 6
AIC = 31616.93
```

**7. HOW TO CHECK COMPLETE MODEL'S FIT?**

I tried to do this as follows using different values for replacing the question marks, but got this error: **Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector**

```
KaplanMeier = survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = data)

plot(KaplanMeier)
lines(predict(final, newdata=list(group = "A",
                                 sex = ?, 
                                 age = ?, 
                                 comorbidity_score = ?,
                                 type="quantile",
                                 p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),
                                 seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),
                                 col="blue"))
lines(predict(final, newdata=list(group = "B",
                                 sex = ?, 
                                 age = ?, 
                                 comorbidity_score = ?,
                                 type="quantile",
                                 p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),
                                 seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),
                                 col="blue"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's been a while since this question was first posted, but I came across this resource that may help you. Take a look at the slide that's third from the bottom: [http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams588/Lecture_5_AFT.pdf](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/%7Ezhu/ams588/Lecture_5_AFT.pdf)

It seems that you can fit a couple of models, and given that, for example, the exponential distribution is a subset of the Gamma distribution, you can use the log-likelihood values to determine which ones are better fit -- but only for nested models. Smaller log-likelihood values is indicative of a better fit (i.e., closer to 0). However, the slides also state that you assume that the Gamma distribution is reasonable to start with.

There's also this paper here as well: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2376927/pdf/89-6601120a.pdf

Hope this helps someone else who comes across a similar question.